# AutoComplete Decorator

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, decorator, swingx

I am implementing autocompleteDecorator in a Swing application. My codes are like this.

```
public inventory_purchase() {
    initComponents();
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this.combo);
}

public void autocomplete(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/jpublisher/pub", "APP", "app");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query="SELECT * FROM INVENTORY";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            combo.addItem(rs.getString("CATEGORY"));
        }
    }
    catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data cannot be loaded. Error!!");
    }   

}
```

This Autocomplete Decorator works only when I call this function in

```
formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){autocomplete();}
```

How can I use this autocomplete with a key listener? Like :

```
private void comboKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    autocomplete();
}
```

Is there any other simple process to use autocomplete from database?

Comment: you shouldn't be instantiating a db connection every time you need to issue a statement.  you should do it when your app starts and keep it in a singleton

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  Here's a quick example:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KeyBindings extends Box{
    public KeyBindings(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        final JLabel text = new JLabel("Original Text");
        add(text);

        Action action = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                text.setText("New Text");
            }};
         String keyStrokeAndKey = "control H";
         KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyStrokeAndKey);
         getInputMap().put(keyStroke, keyStrokeAndKey);
         getActionMap().put(keyStrokeAndKey, action);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new KeyBindings());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for key bindings; as an aside, `pack()` invokes `validate()`.

Comment: @trashgod - Touché.  Don't know how I got in the habit of doing that - must be the copy/paste syndrome.  I'll get that out of there (although I'm not sure I'm dedicated enough to pull it out of all my samples, I'll try not to do that in the future).

Comment: Actually I am Not trying key binding. It's just an autocomplete combobox in which data will be populated from database. Please help me.

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara Ah - in that case you'll probably want to use a `DocumentListener`:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html

Comment: But when I use document listner the autocompletedecorator does not work anymore.